# Wordpress: pages are not updating despite emptying caches

Tags: wordpress

I have used the plugin All-in-One WP Migration to get the site from the development environment to the live site (you can export and import a complete website).

Some pages have updated correctly but not all of the pages (they remain in the old style and structure).

I have deleted my browser cache several times (tried several browsers on different computers even), deleted caches created by plugins several times (tried deactivating those plugins as well). However, despite trying to delete all the caches I can think of, some pages are just not updating. As the page templates for these pages do not exist anymore on the server, I am at a complete loss as to what's preventing all the pages from updating correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your hosting server can also have a cache, this is commonly overlooked in these types of issues.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I don't see any options in the hosting settings to delete caches (I'm with ionos/1&1). Is there anything I can do about this or just have to wait?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that hosting provider, but often you just have to wait. If you want to test if this is the problem, you could try changing one of the filenames that are being cached and update it in the code, and see if that triggers a change.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask is your site already live? Cause I had the same issue as yours and I manage to get it updated by deleting the cache by "Flush Cache" on my WordPress admin page

Once you logged in to your WordPress admin site you'll find this and click that
[Flush Cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhkbY.png)

[Flush Cache (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI1bd.png)

I am not so sure why that happens but I am thinking it might be because from the server and might need sometime on updating any changes made. It happened to me also when I have some updates on my site then once I save everything and go to my site, still the old ones are being shown but when I `Flush Cache` then it shows up the new ones... I think the reason because it still shows up the old ones is  probably of the cache from the old ones in the server and by flushing them is being able to show the updated ones.

Comment: Yes the site is live and unfortunately, I don't have that option in my admin panel. The host is ionos/1&1 and I can't find any options for caching in their settings unfortunately. But maybe it's to do with the server..

Comment: Hmmm... that's strange cause I think that option is there within wordpress... have you tried going to the dashboard and check this at the upper part?  Flush Cache (2)

Comment: No, that option is not a standard feature for WP, nor is it  part of standard hosting packages. I've developed dozens of WP sites for different clients using many different hosting providers over the years. I'm guessing it is part of a specific "managed wordpress" hosting package offered by certain providers where they are managing some of the installation for you.